# Image not resizing to parent or grandparents using %

Tags: html, css

i am making a modal from ww3 school website. I have a button that opens the modal and i tried to add an image inside the modal but i cant make the image resize based off any of its parent/grandparent divs.

i tried max width, width.. no success

it wont resize in % only in pixels, as i understand % only works if containing div has a defined height which is does so what gives??

```js
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content/Box */
.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: 15% auto; /* 15% from the top and centered */
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 60%; /* Could be more or less, depending on screen size */
  height: 50px;
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  color: #aaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/// END OF MODAL CSS /// END OF MODAL CSS/// END OF MODAL CSS/// END OF MODAL CSS/// END OF MODAL CSS/// END OF MODAL CSS/// END OF MODAL CSS/// END OF MODAL CSS/// END OF MODAL CSS

.image_holder{
height: 100px;
width: 100px;
}


.modal__img{
  max-height: 50%;
  max-width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<body>

<button id="myBtn">Book</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
  <div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
   <div class="modal-content">
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
      <div class="image_holder">
            <img class="modal__img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300.png/09f/fff"> 
        </div>
      <p>accomodationaccomodationaccomodationaccomodationaccomodationaccomodationaccomodation </p>

  </div>

</div>
<!-- Modal content -->




</body>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the changes I've made for the image to expand the full width of its parent.

```
    .image_holder{
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
    }


    .modal__img{
      max-height: 100%;
      max-width: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
    }
```

Is that what you wanted to achieve?

https://codepen.io/Angel-SG/pen/aPNWBZ

Comment: that doesn't seem to do it. i want it to fit inside the white rectangle ".modal-content"

Comment: the white rectangle sizes around 1180px width per 90 ish height. I don't think it can fit a 300 x 300 px image and a paragraph in that space. I have updated the codepen link with the white rectangle taking up to the content dimensions. https://codepen.io/Angel-SG/pen/aPNWBZ

Comment: I dont think we're on the same page. In my orignal upload the white rectangle ".modal-content" is 90% width and height 50px; i just want the 300x300 blue square to fit into that space using % but nothing happens when i change ".modal__img" to 1% or 100% the blue rectangle is the same size?? i appreciate your time

Comment: I think we are on the same page here, but there isn't a physically way to put a 300 x 300 element inside of a div with 50px height. The only way you could achieve something similar of what you are looking for would be inserting the image as a background image and position the background to cover. But even like that the image ratio wouldn't look okay. Hope that makes sense!

Comment: i've managed to do it here https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MZyBjJ do you see what's happeneing? the image will fit the holder no matter what height and width you give the parent image holder, albeit squished up. I cannot make this effect happen in the original post, the image should be jammed into its holder but it seems to be sizing off something else, i can't figure it out

Comment: I found what was happening! Your CSS comments were wrong formatted and they were messing up the styles. I have also changed some stuff in the classes. Take a look here https://codepen.io/Angel-SG/pen/aPNWBZ

Comment: thanks so much! i didn't have time to view your comment earlier. appreciate it

Comment: you're welcome! Just vote my answer if it was helpful to you :)